# How to initialize beans in imported jar with properties from application properties

Tags: java, spring, import, jar, properties

I have a spring app that imports one jar.
Within the jar there is a bean annonated with `@Configuration` for example and it has some fields annotated with `@Value`.

If I import the jar into my app, provide the `app.properties` file in the app(not in imported jar), how can those value be used for initializing fields in the bean?
When I start an app I got message:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

And my bean in imported jar look like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class SomeConfig {
    @Value("${some.name}")
    private String field;
    ...
}
```

When the `app.propeties` file is in the imported jar there are no problems.

Comment: Where is it in your application? It has to be on the classpath how it gets on the classpath (jar or file) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")` or using placeholders as described in docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: I ran app from Idea. The app was in maven project with packaging: pom(top module in project). Once I moved app to new sub module with packaging jar it is fine :)